# Is there a way I can artificially heat up my machine to do some cooling testing?

Tags: overheating, stress-testing

So I have a case mod that I have been working on. It's a small form factor so I require a creative way to cool the system. I am in the testing stages so I am looking for the best way to crank up the heat through the system. Now by heat i mean the CPU running say a few videos and going through some extremely heavy counting program or something like that.

Is there any program out there that creates heavy processing for a stress test such as this already? I really just need to measure how much heat this system will put off under a heavy load. Not trying to destroy the system either. Not really looking for cooling solutions and would rather focus on the program if at all possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [man stress](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/stress.1.html), [gpu test](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/) as well as the benchmarks within [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/). At least one of those will meet your needs.